# How do I open file or directory in terminal without typing the full directory path?

Tags: command-line

I am currently accessing the following directory

```
user:/var/www/html$
```

Whenever I want to access a file or directory for example `var/www/html/nauv/application/bootstrap.php` or `var/www/html/nauv/system/config` how can I edit the following file using vim or open the directory using `cd` command without having to type in the full path to the file or directory?

Comment: Switch to `zsh`, type `v/w/h/n/a/b`, press TAB and let zsh expand it to the full path.

Comment: also if you have edited that file recently you can use the up arrow to pull the command from your history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the first letters of the directory/file you mean, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If there is only one possible option it will auto-complete it, else after pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, it will show you a list with all options starting with the letters you typed.

And you can navigate to a folder using `cd`. Example:

You are in your home directory `/home/your_username/` or for short `~/`

- go to `~/Downloads/` by typing

  ```
  cd Downloads
  ```
- go to `/var/www/html/` by typing

  ```
  cd /var/www/html
  ```

Leading `/` means that you have an absolute reference, beginning at the file system root.

`./` would mean the current directory and `../` would mean the directory above.

Hope this could help you. Try also searching for Ubuntu terminal tutorials.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to know. Sorry am a bit new with the command line. Thanks to everyone for the tips.

Comment: Please accept the answer instead of just commenting if you think this one was most helpful, because then you and me both will earn reputation and otherns can see that your problem is solved. You could at least vote the answer up. Thank you!

Comment: Once we all were new to everything. I started participating in here only 4 days ago. But we are here to learn from and help each other, so no need to apologize! :D

Answer (score 1):

You know you can use the tab key for path and filename auto-completion?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Symbolic link using this below command

`ln -s var/www/html/nauv/application/bootstrap.php /home/nasvil/bootstrap`

This will create a link named "bootstrap" to real file in your HOME FOLDER.

You can also directly edit this file.

This is a kind of Desktop Shortcut, which is found in Windows.